# error in the Data Source of Entity Framework Data Model

Tags: sql, database, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm encountring this error :

[image: Error]

When I try to execute this code :

```
db = new MyModelContainer();

var _projets = from d in db.Projets
               select d;

string toto = string.Empty;

foreach (var projet in _projets)
{
    toto += projet.Adresse;
}
```

This is my App.Config file :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add ... ;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\db.sdf; />
</connectionStrings>
```

I created the database in a folder called `Database/` in the root folder of the app.

To resolve the problem, I have to move the database to `bin/Debug/Database/db.sdf`

What I sould change in the the connectionString to make it point to the other folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put full path to the database file in your connectionn string

Comment: And when I move the project to another environment ?